# How to get ${basedir} value (or other properties) within the Mojo.execute()?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, mojo

I'm trying to get the value of the `${basedir}` within a Mojo. I thought I could see that as a normal System property but

```
System.getProperty("basedir")
```

returns `null`.

```java
public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    String baseDir = ???
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done by injecting the [`MavenProject`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) and invoking the [`getBaseDir()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getBasedir%28%29) method, like this:

```java
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true, required = true)
    private MavenProject project;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
        String baseDir = project.getBaseDir();
    }

}
```

The [`@Parameter`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Parameter.html) is used to inject the value `${project}`, which [resolves](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html) to the current project being built from the Maven session.

[Using annotations](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html) requires the following dependency on the Maven plugin:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope> <!-- annotations are needed only to build the plugin -->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Upvoted. `@Component` still works, but is now deprecated for `MavenProject`, should use `@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true)`. Thanks!

Comment: @donsenior You're right, I edited with the non-deprecated method, and added some more explanation.